# U-boot: Dual Boot + Dummy Kernel + Modified Splash Image

Tags: android, linux, kernel, u-boot

I want to integrate a dual boot feature into u-boot. During the execution of the SPL, the u-boot.img gets authenticated. If it get authenticated correctly, Android ICS is started. If not, a dummy kernel shall be started, which does nothing more then showing an error message (maybe as the boot logo).

Thus, I do have three challenges:

1. I need to pass u-boot.img different parameters, to boot different kernel images based on the authentication process.
2. I need to integrate some kind of dummy kernel, which does nothing but just displaying a boot screen.
3. I need to modify this boot screen with my own version.

I know how to perform the last step, since the boot screen seems to be a zip file, which needs to be replaces. However, could you give me hints regarding the first and second task?

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean authenticate the kernel. Is that correct? If you want to do that, U-Boot has that capability. You can do all of this in a script that will either boot the authenticated kernel or display a splash screen.

For the splash screen, there are several ways to do it. One way would use a U-Boot command, depending on version, to display a bitmap stored in flash or on an SD card. The other way would require you to convert a bitmap to a header file and rebuild the U-Boot image. I can give you directions for this if you tell me where you want to store the image and what version of U-Boot you are using. Also for rebuilding the image, you will need to know which source you are using, so you can add the header with the bitmap. Also what is the data format for the display (RGB 565, Etc.)?

Where is the kernel going to be stored and by what method are you going to authenticate it?

Comment: Hi

I am using the latest build of Denx u-boot (http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot). The device is a PandaBoard ES (omap4460). The kernel is an Android kernel. The kernel, the u-boot.img as well as the potential bitmap is stored on the MMC.
The authentication is done by hashing u-boot.img during the execution of the SPL, decrypting the hash with a key derived from the hardware platform and compare it to a stored value.

Comment: Is this for security purposes? Are you going to have SPL in NAND or NOR? If this is the case I would have SPL and U-Boot in NAND with the boot straps fixed for a NAND boot. U-boot could be modified to authenticate an image before booting it. This would be easier than doing it in SPL which is limited by SRAM.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for your advice. Actually, I need to do it in the SPL, because the key is derived from hardware properties of the SRAM, which are zeroed very early. So I have to derive the key  right after reset. The actual implementation of the authentication scheme is already done. I only need to perform the 3 tasks from above to boot to the corresponding kernel based upon the authentication result. By the way: I am using android 4.0 linaro.

Comment: Steven, could you give me directions on how to display the splash screen? I am using a PandaBoard ES 1.1 (OMAP 4460) with the Chipsee extension board. Thanks in advance

Comment: Peter, this will depend on which U-Boot commands that you have available. Can you add the output from the help command in U-Boot. This will show all of the available commands. If you do not have the needed commads they could be added or you could buil the splash screen into the U-Boot image.

Comment: I can provide the commands soonish. However, could you give me references on how to build the splash screen into u-boot image? The official website states that the current u-boot version does not support the pandaboard (http://pandaboard.org/content/splash-screen-support-u-boot). However, some people try to hack around this (http://e2e.ti.com/support/omap/f/849/p/107466/815173.aspx#815173). Do you already have the splash screen up and running on a pandaboard with u-boot?

Comment: Ah, I see they do not have support for the a display at the moment. I have not worked with OMAP 4430; I have worked with DM3730, AM3703, L138, Etc. Printing the help commands here will not help since there is no support. I would create a git branch and start working with the suggestions on e2e.ti.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am very grateful for your efforts!